# Bazel link bcrypt.lib

Tags: c++, windows, boost, bazel

I'm working on a c++ app with bazel. I'm trying to use the uuid library from boost. On windows, this requires linking bcrypt.lib from the windows sdk. I've downloaded and installed the windows sdk in the standard location: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\`.

In my `BUILD` file I have the following:

```
cc_import(
  name = "bcrypt",
  interface_library = "bcrypt.lib",
  system_provided = 1,
)

cc_library(
    ...
    deps = [
        ":bcrypt",
    ],
)
```

However, this looks for `bcrypt.lib` in the current directory and fails to find it. It works if I copy/paste the correct `bcrypt.lib` for my architecture into the local directory, but that's not going to work for other users on other architectures.

What's the correct way for me to link this lib on Windows (and how would I need to link this on other systems like MacOS or Debian, etc?)?

**--EDIT--**

Here is the error I get:

```bash
trader.lib(utils.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol BCryptCloseAlgorithmProvider referenced in function "private: void __cdecl boost::uuids::detail::random_provider_base::destroy(void)" (?destroy@random_provider_base@detail@uuids@boost@@AEAAXXZ)
trader.lib(utils.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol BCryptGenRandom referenced in function "public: void __cdecl boost::uuids::detail::random_provider_base::get_random_bytes(void *,unsigned __int64)" (?get_random_bytes@random_provider_base@detail@uuids@boost@@QEAAXPEAX_K@Z)
trader.lib(utils.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol BCryptOpenAlgorithmProvider referenced in function "public: __cdecl boost::uuids::detail::random_provider_base::random_provider_base(void)" (??0random_provider_base@detail@uuids@boost@@QEAA@XZ)
bazel-out\x64_windows-fastbuild\bin\tests\lib\trader\trader_test.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 3 unresolved externals
```

Here's my code in question:

```cpp
#include <boost/uuid/uuid.hpp>
#include <boost/uuid/uuid_generators.hpp>
#include <boost/uuid/uuid_io.hpp>

...

boost::uuids::random_generator rg = boost::uuids::random_generator();
boost::uuids::uuid id = rg();
string id_str = boost::uuids::to_string(id);
```

Comment: Did you test https://github.com/nelhage/rules_boost? https://github.com/nelhage/rules_boost/blob/ce61bed8f16632ac7ed644940ec7547d5de8b4cb/test/uuid_test.cc#L4

Comment: @Vertexwahn I am using `rules_boost` but didn't mention it. Hmmm... I just git cloned and ran that test and it passed without needing a link to bcrypt. Weird.

Comment: @Vertexwahn I think that test is passing because it uses a nil generator. When I try to use `random_generator` in that test, I get the same error.

Comment: I see the error caused for not referencing the bcrypt.lib in your code.  Something like       ```#include <bcrypt.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "bcrypt.lib")```

Comment: @Adam Can you provide a failing "test" as an PR to the `rules_boost` repo?

Comment: @Vertexwahn

https://github.com/nelhage/rules_boost/pull/411

Comment: @SG_Bazel adding `#pragma comment(lib, "bcrypt.lib")` worked! Thanks!